# Material UI dropdown is uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to Material UI and have an issue.  I have a reusable dropdown filter that is populated from an array.  Everything works exactly how I want it to, but I keep getting a console error that the component is changing and uncontrolled input.  The problem is, if I add a default value (value='') to eliminate the uncontrolled error, the dropdown will not display my selected filtering option in the input, just a blank.  How can I control the component but still show my  the user the filtering option selected.

```
const status = [
    {id: 1, label: '...', value: ''}, 
    {id: 2, label: 'Active', value: 48},
    {id: 3, label: 'Inactive', value: -1},
    {id: 4, label: 'On Hold', value: 48654},
    {id: 5, label: 'Out Of Spec', value: 50989},
]

<DropdownFltr
     prompt='Status...'
     options={status}
     onChange={handleFilterValue}
 />



export default function DropdownFltr(props) {
    const { error=null, options, prompt, onChange, value, ...other } = props;

         return(
            <>
            <FormControl>
                <InputLabel>{prompt}</InputLabel> 
                <Select
                    value=''  // <<< Causes issues, but fixed uncontrolled error
                    onChange={onChange}
                    {...other}
                    {...(error && {error:true, helperText:error})}
                >
                    {options.map((option, id) => (
                        <MenuItem 
                            key={option.id} 
                            value={option.value} 
                        >
                            {option.label}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            </>
            )
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the original error?

Comment: Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: I also get this as a warning:    Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are ``, `48`, `-1`, `48654`, `50989`

Comment: Have you tried using `defaultValue` instead of `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the default Value in the Component Select

```
<Select
    defaultValue={''}
/>
```